# How to convert an array into a number in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, integer

I want to convert an array in one large number in PHP.

For example, I have an array $array:

```
$array[0] = 10;
$array[1] = 20;
$array[2] = 30;
$array[3] = 40;
```

I want this to be:

```
$one_large_number = 10203040;
```

I read somewhere the way to convert an array into a string, but that won't allow me to perform mathematical operations, right?

So anyone know how to convert the array to one continuous number?

Thanks.

Comment: Multiply the first number by 100, and add the second number. Multiply result by 100, and add third number. Multiply result by 100 and add fourth number. And so forth.

Comment: That will only work in this case.

Comment: traverse the whole array elements in one variable by concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
join("", $array);
```

A little more about it in here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_join.asp

http://codepad.org/Dv0zdtaJ - live example. As you can see, you can easily perform further mathematical functions with that number :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function as:

```
$array = array(10, 20, 30, 40);
$one_large_number = implode("", $array);
// Output: 10203040
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use implode it's an alias of join

```
$array[0] = 10;
$array[1] = 20;
$array[2] = 30;
$array[3] = 40;
$one_large_number = implode('',$array);
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you'll get a number:

```
intval(implode('', $array));
```